# Chained shared_ptr vector initialization

Tags: c++

I use the following example code to initialize vector of shared_ptr:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Song
{
    std::wstring artist;
    std::wstring title;
    Song(const std::wstring& artist_, const std::wstring& title_) :
        artist{ artist_ }, title{ title_ } {}
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<shared_ptr<Song>> v {
  make_shared<Song>(L"Bob Dylan", L"The Times They Are A Changing"),
  make_shared<Song>(L"Aretha Franklin", L"Bridge Over Troubled Water"),
  make_shared<Song>(L"Thalía", L"Entre El Mar y Una Estrella")
};
 
// how to initialize these following shared_ptr chains?
 vector<shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<Song>>> long_Song;
 shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<Song>>>>> ptr_long_Song; 

return 0;
}
```

But for chained shared_ptr (is this right name?), how to initialize them, like the last two declarations?

Comment: Why do you need smart pointers? Won't `vector<Song>` do?

Comment: just some legacy reasons. The actual code is more complicated so I use the above example to show the question

Comment: just use nested initialiser lists/`make_shared`? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: don't understand what "nested initialiser" means? make_shared<Song>(make_shared<Song>(L"A",L"B"), make_shared<Song>(L"C", L"D")) or make_shared<Song>((L"A", L"B"), (L"C", L"D")) wouldn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested type to initalize a type which is nested one level deeper like that

```
 vector<shared_ptr<Song>> v {
  make_shared<Song>(L"Bob Dylan", L"The Times They Are A Changing"),
  make_shared<Song>(L"Aretha Franklin", L"Bridge Over Troubled Water"),
  make_shared<Song>(L"Thalía", L"Entre El Mar y Una Estrella")};
  using songs = decltype(v);
  
 vector<shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<Song>>>> long_Song {std::make_shared<songs>(v)};
 using long_songs = decltype(long_Song);
 shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<Song>>>>> ptr_long_Song { std::make_shared<long_songs>(long_Song)};
```

Comment: ok, this works. A side question to long_Song: how to use iterator for long_Song to extract elements?